# How to remove blank after td

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-table, iban

I want to display an IBAN number in a html mail. To improve readability I want to add a blank after every 4th sign. To also provide a good usability I want to do this with padding, so the user can copy & paste the IBAN into his online banking system without any blanks. To achieve this I have to use a table, because Microsoft Outlook ignores padding on other elements:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-right:5px;">
      IBAN:
    </td>
    <td style="padding-right:5px;">
      XX01
    </td>
    <td style="padding-right:5px;">
      2345
    </td>
    <td style="padding-right:5px;">
      6789
    </td>
    <td style="padding-right:5px;">
      0123
    </td>
    <td>
      4567
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

(See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1c2dcfdy/))

My problem: When I copy & paste the IBAN a blank is added after each td element. Is there a way to remove these blanks with html or css?

Comment: You will have to remove all whitespace between the `td` elements.

Comment: What do you mean “Microsoft Outlook ignores padding on other elements”? Which elements and what CSS have you tried? Have you tried `div`s with `display: inline-block;`?

Comment: If padding is the issue, what about a border of the same color as the background?

Comment: @CBroe: That doesn't help: https://jsfiddle.net/hwuhka3c/

Comment: @Xufox: I tried span and div, both paddings are ignored by Outlook (also margin by the way)

Comment: @TomWoodward: Padding is not the problem, without padding it also adds blanks

Comment: Does outlook show padding if you use `display: table-cell` on a `span` element? [Like this](https://jsfiddle.net/1c2dcfdy/19/)

Comment: I meant ditch the table and use divs but use border instead of padding. Like https://jsfiddle.net/1c2dcfdy/18/ Seems to work but I don't have Outlook to test.

Comment: @Oriol: Outlook ignores the "display: table-cell" and this also adds the blanks in webmail clients

Comment: @TomWoodward: Sadly it doesn't. Outllok isn't supporting display at all according to this site: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/